# How to change SELinux configuration persistently?

Tags: selinux

With `setsebool <name_of_variable> <on/off>` it is possible to change selinux configuration. However the changes are gone after reboot. How can we do these changes persistently?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. There is the `-P` switch (see the [manual page for setsebool](https://linux.die.net/man/8/setsebool)), which changes the policy on the disk:

```
setsebool -P <name_of_variable> <on/off>
```

does the job.

Comment: @Christopher Not sure where it was said that it is RHEL6, but I suppose link to general manual page is quite enough. But thanks for the reference.